# How can I get rid of duplicate icons in /usr/share/applications?

Tags: gnome, startup-applications

As the folder name says `/usr/share/applications`... are these all my applications installed in the system?

Will deleting a program's icon in below pics mean uninstalling it from the system permanently?

For example, I see Amazon & Cheese icons twice... Files icon thrice

[image: icons in /usr/share/applications]

[image: icons in /usr/share/applications]

This is a freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 and I've just installed Audacious, MPV player, Dconf & GNOME Tweaks.

My intention:

1. How can I know which icon is the actual application that I have to keep? For example I want to remove Amazon completely from my system. Of the two Archive Manager icons, I want to keep the actual working one and remove the other...
2. How can I know the name of application that can be removed via command line, for example

   ```
   sudo apt remove Amazon
   sudo apt remove Audacious Qt Interface 
   sudo apt remove Cheese-not-in-use
   sudo apt remove Files1-not-in-use  
   sudo apt remove Files2-not-in-use
   ```

Final Goal:

If I want Audacious, MPV player, Dconf, Files, Cheese, InputMethod, Keyboard, Gparted, Displays, Dock, Disks, Calendar only, then I want to see only 12 icons in this folder.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Desktop Entries are either created by the applications or by the user as per his convenience. Not all Desktop Entries refer to application. Remember it might happen a user has created a script and to run that he used a Desktop  Entry. So **not all desktop entry refer to application**. It is also to be noted that not all Desktop Entries are in `/usr/share/applications`.

- > are these all my applications installed in the system?

  Most probably yes if all these are created by system/application itself. Desktop entries are created at the time of installation of a software (if software knows how to create that like Google Chrome does but Netbeans doesn't).
- > deleting icon in below pics, means uninstalling it from the system permanently?

  Not really. You are just deleting a way (shortcut) to launch a specific application **not an application** which will still exist after the `.desktop` file is deleted.
- > how to know which icon is the actual application that i have to keep

  You need to open duplicate desktop entries through a text editor and determine which functionality it offers or for what purpose it is there. Multiple desktop entries must have created multiple shortcuts in app drawer but out of those multiple desktop entries only 1 is visible and every other will be hidden due to `NoDisplay=true` in their description. That's why only 1 is visible in app drawer. It may also contain a line `OnlyShownIn` or `NotShowIn` to show or hide in specific DE.You can learn more about it at [Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html)
- > how to know the name of application that can be remove via command line

  For this refer [N0rbert's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1103969/816190)
- > if i want Audacious, MPV player, Dconf, Files, Cheese, InputMethod, Keyboard, Gparted, Displays, Dock, Disks, Calendar only then i want to see only 12 icons in this folder.

  No. Some entries like that of Bluetooth are defined by the system and it needs that to properly display it while using a search.

Comment: Nice, I'd like to mention that multiple entries are used for different purposes, e.g. `Files` has different `.desktop`- files, one is used in the dashboard, another one will be used in the taskbar, so none of them should be deleted.

Comment: @mook765 Yeah that's what I meant by *determine which functionality it offers* in point 3.

Comment: @Kulfy good answer, but I disagree with the first point. Those are only the applications that offer a GUI. Most CLI only applications don't come with a desktop entry.

Comment: @danzel I agree. IMO GUI is also offered by an executable file to make app interactive. But if the desktop entry is created by user it might be used to just execute a script. One of my friend created the desktop entry to execute a script because he was facing some sort of problems and that script has to be executed once in a while.

Comment: @danzel *Most CLI only applications don't come with a desktop entry*: Python also have a Desktop Entry by default. For reference you can look into the screenshot in question body. :)

Comment: @Kulfy ...which is used for python based GUIs AFAIK. You are right, desktop entries can be used for all sorts of things, and maybe it depends on how one defines "application". I just wanted to say that uninstalling every application that has a desktop entry doesn't necessarily mean there is no application left on the system.

Comment: @danzel Nope. Just execute desktop entry of python. It will open a terminal with `python` already executed. I agree with you last point. And yes thats completely different what you mentioned in earlier comment. I guess ;)

Answer (score 4):

<sup>If you went here with MacOS habits, do not expect that pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Delete</kbd> will remove things.</sup>

In Ubuntu this folder contains many **.desktop* files for installed applications.

If they were installed by APT then you can use the power of `dpkg` to manage them.

So you can find Amazon with:

```
ls -1 /usr/share/applications/ | grep -i amazon
```

it will return

> ```
> com.canonical.launcher.amazon.desktop
> ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop
> ```

Afterwards you can find their packages with `dpkg -S`:

```
dpkg -S com.canonical.launcher.amazon.desktop ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop
```

> ```
> ubuntu-web-launchers: /usr/share/applications/com.canonical.launcher.amazon.desktop
> ubuntu-web-launchers: /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop
> ```

and finally you can remove the related package:

```
sudo apt purge ubuntu-web-launchers
```

---

Programmatical way is below (**warning: be careful with its execution - check the list of packages being removed before proceeding**):

```
export ICONNAME=Amazon
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -S $(ls -1 /usr/share/applications/ | grep -i $ICONNAME) | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/://' | sort -u)
```

Comment: I see that [Kulfy's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1103971/66509) contains needed information. But my answer contains practical method. So both answers complete each other (thanks @Kulfy).

Comment: @N0rbert That's why I've referred your answer to complete my answer :)

Comment: @PRATAP it may lead to unpredictable behavior because of package dependencies. You should try this idea on clean VM with snapshots. I can't offer any warranty that system wont became broken completely.

Comment: @N0rbert i am trying to use the command you mentioned under programmatical way.. as i am new.. i am confused with those two commands.. do i need to run those commands one by one or it needs to keep in script? i tried second command by replacing `$ICONNAME` with `Sudoku`

Comment: pratap@PRATAP:~$ sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -S $(ls -1 /usr/share/applications/ | grep -i Sudoku) | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/://' | sort -u)
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *Sudoku.desktop*
[sudo] password for pratap: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
pratap@PRATAP:~$

Comment: You do something wrong. Executing both two commands for Sudoku gives me prompt about removal `gnome-sudoku` package.

Comment: should i run commands one by one?

Comment: Yes of course - in the same terminal (1st is variable declaration, 2nd uses this variable).